# Struct variable and struct member in function definition

Tags: c, struct

Consider the code:

```
#define STRINGMAX 50

struct GIFTS {
    char whofor[STRINGMAX];
    char city[STRINGMAX];
    float weight;
    struct DIMENSIONS {
        float width;
        float length;
        float height;
    } dim;
} gifts[STRINGMAX];
```

And function definition:

```
void takeString(char * structvar, char structarr[], int arrpos) {
    while (scanf("%[^\n]%*c]", structarr[arrpos].structvar) != EOF) {
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c]", structarr[arrpos].structvar);
    }

}
```

It gives me an error:

> request for member ‘structvar’ in something not a structure or union

Is there any way to pass a struct member in this case? I've seen some similar topics here about doing that, but i wasn't able to introduce that ideas into my code (I'm a complete C beginner).
I would appreciate any help, especially an clear example in code.

Btw. I know i shouldn't use scanf, but it's just for example. I'll do something else when I'll know how to pass the struct member in function parameter.

Comment: `structarr` is of type `char *`, did you mean `structvar`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your loop reading input will require the user to input the same data *twice*.

Comment: Since none of the function parameters is a struct, this question doesn't make any sense. Please edit it so it becomes clear what you mean.

Comment: i really don't know how to name it. I wanted to be able to specify struct members in function arguments to append strings to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your problem (as I understand it), it really can't be done. Consider making the `takeString` function only take a single string argument, and read input into that string.

Then pass the correct string from the array and structure to the function. This can be done by *another* function which takes a pointer (or index) to the structure to read.

Perhaps something like this pseudo-code:

```
void takeString(char *string)
{
    scanf("...", string);
}

void takeStructure(int arrayIndex)
{
    ...
    takeString(gifts[arrayIndex].city);
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's something I ican work on! So it isn't possible to pass member (in this example above member 'city') in function arguments?

Comment: @angrysomoan No it's not possible to pass the symbol of a member.